# Running app on real phone rather than Expo Go

Tags: reactjs, expo

I just followed the following tutorial - https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-use-react-native-geolocation-to-get-postal-address

It works great and I used the Expo Go iOS simulator in visual studio code. However I want to test it on my real phone now.

This may be an obvious question, but how do I run it on my own phone instead of the simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Expo Go app on your real phone and scan the QR code that shows app on your VS code terminal window when you start the app. There is nothing else you need to do.